# Cannot enforce trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, decimal, string.format

I am trying to read values from excel sheet cells, where I find values like 123,10000. So there are always 5 decimal places. Now, I read in this value from a cell like this:

```
reportedAmount = _converter.ToDecimalOrZero(row[25].ToString());
```

The `ToDecimalOrZero` method looks like this:

```
internal decimal ToDecimalOrZero(string v)
    {
        String formattedDecimalInput = String.Format("{0:0.00000}", v);
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(formattedDecimalInput);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("{0:0.00000}", 0));
        }
    }
```

Now, the issue is that the returned values will always have no trailing zeroes, regardless of how the input is. What I notice when doing some simple debugging is that the method that reads out the value from a cell is the one that removes the zeroes. However, what is confusing to me is that `String.Format("{0:0.00000}", v)` does not return the value with 5 decimal places, but returns the same format that the value we gave to it had (the one without trailing zeroes). Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: `String.Format("{0:0.00000}", v)` -- `v` is a string, and there aren't any formatting styles for a string -- you put a string in, you get the same string out. The `0.00000` is a *numeric* format style, it applies to numbers. A string is not a number, and the `0.00000` will have no effect

Comment: Your other confusion is that numbers are inherently just... values. They aren't formatted in any particular way: a number has no concept of what decimal separator it uses, or what character to use for the negative sign, or how many trailing zeros to print. All of that stuff matters when you turn a number into a string: it's part of that process of turning the number into something printable, but isn't a property of the number itself. (It's true that `decimal`, through a quirk in its implementation, can represent a value with trailing zeros, but you should not rely on this)